# Why keeps deployment to Appstore connect failing because of "Asset validation failed (90035)" with Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, gradlew

This is the exact error message:

> Asset validation failed (90035)
> Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all. The file at path [Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/android/gradlew] is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Automatic signing is enabled. The console does not log any errors during build, only during the upload in the transporter.

I don't understand why the IOS build even tries to access that file.

flutter clean, deleting podfile and recreating ios directory (and android directory) does not work. Deactivating automatic signing and reactivating it has no effect.

Thank you for any help:)

Answer (score 1):

So the error was that for some reason gradlew got included in the pubspec.yaml under assets. I have no idea why it happened, but removing the line solved the problem

Comment: I checked `pubspec.yaml` and see that all folders that exist in folder android were added as assets! How that happened is beyond me. Removing all those listed android folders from `pubspec.yaml` solved the problem.